# How do I fit the td width of different tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The width of the actual **td** is a real number, but I do not know if `offsetWidth` returns only integers. Are there any other properties that return the length of the cell in real number? In chrome's developer tools, press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to see the length, which is different. Can I make it easier to get to the length if I use jQuery?

```js
function fitWidth(selector1, selector2) {
  console.log('fitWidth is excuted');
  let tableHeadElements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector1);
  let tableBodyElements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector2);
  for (let i = 0; i < tableHeadElements.length; i++) {
    let tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow = tableHeadElements[i].firstElementChild.children; // head의 첫번째 tr
    let tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow = tableBodyElements[i].firstElementChild.children; // body의 첫번째 tr
    console.log("body tr count: " + tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow.length);
    for (let j = 0; j < tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow.length; j++) {
      let headCell = tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow[j];
      let bodyCell = tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow[j];
      console.log("head-cell width: " + headCell.clientWidth, "body-cell width: " + bodyCell.clientWidth);
      /*
      headCell.style.width = (bodyCell.offsetWidth) + "px";
      headCell.style.width = (bodyCell.scrollWidth) + "px";
      */
      if (headCell.clientWidth != bodyCell.clientWidth) {
        headCell.clientWidth > bodyCell.clientWidth ? bodyCell.style.width = headCell.clientWidth + "px" : headCell.style.width = bodyCell.clientWidth + "px";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead id="a" class="queue-head">
      <tr>
        <td>AppName</td>
        <td>QueueName</td>
        <td>Server</td>
        <td>Service</td>
        <td>ReceptionCount</td>
        <td>ProcessingCount</td>
        <td>QueueCount</td>
        <td>Limit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody id="b" class="queue-body">
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />

  <table border="1">
    <thead class="queue-head">
      <tr>
        <td>AppName</td>
        <td>QueueName</td>
        <td>Server</td>
        <td>Service</td>
        <td>ReceptionCount</td>
        <td>ProcessingCount</td>
        <td>QueueCount</td>
        <td>Limit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody class="queue-body">
      <tr>
        <td>A22</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A22</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />
  <button onclick='fitWidth("queue-head", "queue-body");'>fit width</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the length of the cell`

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa It means td.

Comment: And length means width to you?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa yes...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect%20%22getBoundingClientRect()%22%20which%20returns%20a%20non-rounded%20number.) which returns a non-rounded number.

Both [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) return a rounded integer. These pages state:

> Note: This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for this.

Let's start by the issue first.

You're using the `clientWidth` which according to the documentation.

> **The clientWidth property returns the viewable width of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.**

So when you assign the clientWidth of an element to another's width, it adds the padding as well, which what we want but ignore the borders if we have any, that is what's happening.

Now if we remove the padding this works, if both cells has the same border width, Even if we add `box-sizing: border-box;` since clientWidth doesn't account for the borders there will be no difference.

---

Moving on to `offsetWidth`.

> **The offsetWidth property returns the viewable width of an element in pixels, including padding, border and scrollbar, but not the margin.**

Now this one seems perfect since it includes the borders and the scrollbars as well, so adding `box-sizing: border-box;` will work.

```js
function fitWidth(selector1, selector2) {
  console.log('fitWidth is excuted');
  let tableHeadElements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector1);
  let tableBodyElements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector2);
  for (let i = 0; i < tableHeadElements.length; i++) {
    let tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow = tableHeadElements[i].firstElementChild.children; // head의 첫번째 tr
    let tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow = tableBodyElements[i].firstElementChild.children; // body의 첫번째 tr
    console.log("body tr count: " + tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow.length);
    for (let j = 0; j < tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow.length; j++) {
      let headCell = tableDataOfFirstHeadTableRow[j];
      let bodyCell = tableDataOfFirstBodyTableRow[j];
      console.log("head-cell width: " + headCell.offsetWidth, "body-cell width: " + bodyCell.offsetWidth);
      /*
      headCell.style.width = (bodyCell.offsetWidth) + "px";
      headCell.style.width = (bodyCell.scrollWidth) + "px";
      */
      if (headCell.offsetWidth != bodyCell.offsetWidth) {
        headCell.offsetWidth > bodyCell.offsetWidth ? bodyCell.style.width = headCell.offsetWidth + "px" : headCell.style.width = bodyCell.offsetWidth + "px";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
td{
    max-width:100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead id="a" class="queue-head">
      <tr>
        <td>AppName</td>
        <td>QueueName</td>
        <td>Server</td>
        <td>Service</td>
        <td>ReceptionCount</td>
        <td>ProcessingCount</td>
        <td>QueueCount</td>
        <td>Limit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody id="b" class="queue-body">
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />

  <table border="1">
    <thead class="queue-head">
      <tr>
        <td>AppName</td>
        <td>QueueName</td>
        <td>Server</td>
        <td>Service</td>
        <td>ReceptionCount</td>
        <td>ProcessingCount</td>
        <td>QueueCount</td>
        <td>Limit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody class="queue-body">
      <tr>
        <td>A22</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A22</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHI</td>
        <td>abcd01</td>
        <td>9999</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />
  <button onclick='fitWidth("queue-head", "queue-body");'>fit width</button>
```

Or you can calculate the width yourself.

As pointed [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

If a div has this definition

```
div {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

it's width will be.

```
320px (width)
+ 20px (left + right padding)
+ 10px (left + right border)
+ 0px (left + right margin)
= 350px
```